# Tomcat https POST data

Tags: tomcat, spring-mvc, https

I'm creating a web application with Spring MVC, to run in Tomcat 7.  I have a POST request on a login page, to /account/login, which I want to send over https.

In my web.xml I have:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Login</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/account/login</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>

    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Login-Error</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/account/login-error</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>

    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

And in the tomcat server.xml I have a https connector:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
    SSLEnabled="true" maxThreads="150" scheme="https"
    secure="true" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
    keystoreFile="/path/to/my.cert" keystorePass="password" />
```

When I hit the login page the protocol is always https, and the login procedure itself works fine.

However, when I use the firefox plugin "tamper data" to inspect the POST request, the username and password are in plain text.  I was expecting them to be encrypted - have I missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about this but SSL works on the network layer so, the data flowing from the application layer to ssl layer is unencrypted and packets are encrypted after that. Which could be the reason why you are able to see the data in plain text.